# How to set ACL for SetWindowsHookEx()?

Tags: winapi

It was possible to set a hook on all keyboard/mouse events in Windows XP:

```
 SetWindowsHookEx(WH_JOURNALRECORD, (HOOKPROC)JournalLogProc, GetModuleHandle(NULL), 0);
```

... but in Windows 7, SetWindowsHookEx returning 5 (access denied).

How to set permissions/ACLs the function need? I got the same "access denied" error even if I run my program "As Administrator".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hooks are not securable objects, so you cannot set an ACL for them.  The reason you are getting an error in Win7 is because UAC, which was introduced in Vista, changes the rules of how journal hooks can be used in general.

A journal hook can only be set by an elevated process, and also the process must bypass [User Interface Privilege Isolation (UIPI)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb625963.aspx) by using a UAC manifest that sets `uiAccess=True`.  Note that setting `uiAccess=True` has other ramifications, so be sure you understand what it actually does (see [Windows Integrity Mechanism Design](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb625963.aspx) for details).  It is not enough to simply run the app as an admin anymore.

The only other workaround is to manually change the security policies of the machine to either disable UAC altogether, or to reduce certain security restrictions in the UAC settings.