# Catching the screen saver event

Tags: c++, windows, callback, screensaver

I'm trying to catch the screen saver event. This is my code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "stdio.h"

#include <Windows.h>


HHOOK _hook;

LRESULT CALLBACK HookCallback(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (nCode >= 0)
    {


        LPMSG msg = (LPMSG)lParam;

        if(msg->message == WM_SYSCOMMAND)
        {
            if (msg->wParam == SC_SCREENSAVE)
            {
                std::cout<<"SC_SCREENSAVE\n";
            }
        }

    }

    return CallNextHookEx(_hook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}

void SetHook()
{

    if (!(_hook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_GETMESSAGE, HookCallback,NULL , 0)))
    {
        std::cout<<"Failed to install hook!\n";
    }
}

void ReleaseHook()
{
    UnhookWindowsHookEx(_hook);
}


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    SetHook();

    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {

    }

    ReleaseHook();

    return 0;
}
```

The function `SetWindowsHookEx(WH_GETMESSAGE, HookCallback,NULL , 0)` fails. It returns the code:

> error 1428: Cannot set nonlocal hook without a module handle

.What am I doing wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't Windows have a `GetLastError` function (or something like that) to get more info about why the previous API call failed? Did you try that?

Comment: That looks like only half a message loop too.

Comment: error 1428: Cannot set nonlocal hook without a module handle.

Comment: @Sanich: please [edit] that information into your question.

Comment: The error message is quite clear: the type of hook you are installing requires a module handle, but you passed NULL. Furthermore, the handle must be to a DLL. This is all explained in the documentation for SetWindowsHookEx which you should considering giving a look.

Answer (score 0):

System-Wide hooks require the application to have elevated access.
You need to run your code As Administrator.

Maybe you will be interested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13714289/how-to-set-acl-for-setwindowshookex) question/answer.